# How do I deposit an Ether amount to the smart contract function, namely deposit ? (Metamask version 0.20.7)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask

I have a problem with using the deposit () function on a smart contract. How do you use metamask 0.20.7 ?

```
const contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
contractInstance.deposit({ from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether'))}, function(err, result){ console.log(result); } );
```

How is it so that a user can only click and automatically release it in metamask with a number of 0.1 ETH ? I can't spend that amount when using it, but only get 0 ETH from it.

[Image Here](https://ibb.co/4Z0ms8j)

Answer (score 0):

regarding the issue in the image: I had the issue with MetaMask a couple times too for two reasons. Once it just didn't go through due to a wrong gas setting, the other times the issue was with the separator "0,1" vs "0.1" depending on your language settings.
Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, but it did not work. I thought that using web3js would work, but it didn't work in Metamask.